# WPF - Binding to Public Fields

Tags: c#, wpf

I looked that [video-example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8IRFTq-wIc)

It works fine. But I want some complicate it.

Create one more class. It will be simple wrapper for `Person` class from video-example above

```
public class MetaPerson
{
    public Person Person;
    public String SomeMeta;
}
```

In constructor window write code

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
     InitializeComponent();

     var metaPerson = new MetaPerson
                          {
                              Person = new Person("Lola", "Azazaeva", 25, Gender.Female),
                              SomeMeta = "Eto some meta!"
                          };

       //Setas datacontext
       DataContext = metaPerson;
    }
```

In XAML I wrote like in video-example:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Name}" FontSize="12" Foreground="Red"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

That does't work.

```
        <StackPanel>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Person}">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="12" Foreground="Red"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>
        </StackPanel>
```

That does't work too :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is that you've made the variables as members -- they must be properties in order for binding to work.

```
public class MetaPerson
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public String SomeMeta { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: really works, thx. Still can not get used to the features of WPF